# Get list of occurrances only starting with keyword and separated with list of delimeters

Tags: javascript, regex

#### Quest

For example, i need get all of `(test\d+)` from block, started with keyword `start` and separated with `and`, `&`, `,` delimeters.

```
bla bla start test1, test2, test3 and test4 & test12 but not test5, 
test6 or test33, and start test100.
```

So i should get `test1, test2, test3, test4, test12, test100`

#### Sandbox

I have played with regexes for somewhile and there is halfway solution. [I got blocks correctly, but it extracts only one last occurance](https://regex101.com/r/nE9bU5/2).

`start\s(?:(test\d+)(?:\s?(?:[,&]|and)\s?)?)+`

Comment: because `and ` is one of delimeters as i said it in question.

Comment: @rock321987 or `(?:\,|&|and|start) *(test\d+)` for only capturing `test\d+`. :)

Comment: @AKS yeah that's correct

Comment: @AKS will fail with this `bla bla start test1, test2, test3 and test4 & test12 but not test5, 
test6 and test33, and start test100.`

Comment: @Tim007 Thanks..I will try to update my answer

Comment: @Tim007 see if this works https://regex101.com/r/gN5nD3/2

Comment: @rock321987, I got same as yours, in a minute before. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done in a single regex. You need to do it in 2 steps by using a [`Array.prototype.map()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a callback:

```
var str = 'bla bla start test1, test2, test3 and test4 & test12 but not test5, \ntest6 or test33, and start test100';

var m = str.match(/\bstart((?:\s*(?:[,&]|and)?\s*test\d+\b)+)/g).map(function(val) {
    return val.match(/\btest\d+/g);
})

console.log(m[0]);
//=> ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test12"]

console.log(m[1]);
//=> ["test100"]
```

---

As per comments below here is a PCRE regex to solve it using single regex:

```
(?:\bstart|(?<!^)\G)\s*(?:[,&]|and)?\s*(test\d+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eC3vU3/1)

Comment: Thank you! But can you explain, why it's cannot be done with single one?

Comment: JS regex doesn't support advanced PCRE features like `\G`. Since you need multiple matches and it must start with `start`, you need 2 steps.

Comment: And, one more thing. You said it solves with PCRE? Can you provide regex for PCRE as well?